# Can I get UNC path of a network drive through my code?

Tags: c#, angularjs, path, unc, network-drive

I made a server and many users are accessing it.

Now I want to get Unc path for mapped drive for each user which will of course be different.

Actually I need the complete path in order to access those files in my c# code.

*Taking complete path from user is not an option* as they are not developers.
What I want to do is ...If someone gives me  `Q:`  then I should get absolute path like this  `\\server1\foo`. I have searched but unable to get solution for this.

**Is there any way to do this?**

**In C#(backend) or in angularjs(frontend)**  ?

From [this_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav) I have learned that I cannot get the complete path just by uploading it in  using javascript because For security reasons browsers do not allow this.

can I provide more details on this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WMI` to check for network path. You can use `ManagementClass` object in C#. We can get this information from `Win32_LogicalDisk`, you will be interested in **Name** and **ProviderName** properties.

```
select * from win32_LogicalDisk where driveType = 4

instance of Win32_LogicalDisk
{
    Access = 0;
    Caption = "Z:";
    Compressed = FALSE;
    CreationClassName = "Win32_LogicalDisk";
    Description = "Network Connection";
    DeviceID = "Z:";
    DriveType = 4;
    FileSystem = "NTFS";
    FreeSpace = "1805758038016";
    MaximumComponentLength = 255;
    MediaType = 0;
    Name = "Z:";
    ProviderName = "\\\\<server>\\<path>";
    Size = "2000396742656";
    SupportsDiskQuotas = FALSE;
    SupportsFileBasedCompression = TRUE;
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
    SystemName = "<server>";
    VolumeName = "New Volume";
    VolumeSerialNumber = "<id>";
};
```

**EDIT** : We have to connect using `\\<server>\root\cimv2` to fetch share information from remote machine. Thanks Alex for pointing that out.

Comment: Thos code will not do anything useful when running on server (as drive napping is local machine specific) and can not be used with JavaScript...

Comment: But as per original question, he has option to run code in C#. I am going with that assumption.